# Why is my React code editor component not highlighted by PrismJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prismjs

I just discovered PrismJs and it looks perfect. But for some reason, it doesn't highlight my code in following component :

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Prism from "prismjs";

export default function EditCode() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }, [content]);
  return (
    <section className="codeGlobalContainer">
      <textarea
        className="codeInput"
        value={content}
        onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
      />
      <pre className="codeOutput">
        <code className={`language-javascript`}>{content}</code>
      </pre>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Is there anything missing to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specified on there npm page, but you need to download a themed CSS on there official site : [PrismsJS](https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism-tomorrow&languages=markup+css+clike+javascript)
Then, you just move the CSS file to your directory and import it in your component as usual :

```js
import "../../styles/prism.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

as @FlowRan mentioned you need to `import` any theme you want to use
but
**Note:** you do not need to download the themes separately as they come with the package.
Import your theme in your file by using the `import` statement from-
`'prismjs/themes/prism-{theme-name}.css';`